# List all opened WorkBooks in the Task Bar

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2013, import-from-excel

I am trying to list all the opened workbooks and their corresponding sheets in the task bar after that I should be able to select one workbook of the list and open it. My first try was to to show Excel process in Task-Manager but it only shows one open workbook without detecting the number of sheets.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim name As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")
    For Each names In name
        ListView1.Items.Add(names.MainWindowTitle)
        If names.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(names.MainWindowTitle)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Next I tried to use this code but also I can only display one opened workbook, I don't know how to loop through them. I don't have problem of changing the whole code if you have any other method cause I am not sure that it's the solution.

```
    Dim oXL As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    oXL = TryCast(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)


    oXL.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized

    Dim y As String
    y = oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Name

           ListBox1.Items.Add(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Dim objExcel As Excel.Application = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

    Dim totalWorkBooks As Integer = objExcel.Workbooks.Count

    For i As Integer = 1 To totalWorkBooks

        objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks(i)

        With objWorkBook
            FullName = .FullName
            OnlyName = .Name
```